React Native daily reminder notification using expo-notification
React Native Expo app.
I want to send out a notification every day at 6 p.m., with the ability to snooze it. But instead of going daily at 6 p.m., my app sends a notification only immediately after you open the app, with no snooze button.
I'm using expo-notifications local notification, but I'm open to alternatives.
Do you guys know the issue? Is this a good use case for local notifications? Should I change to a different library?
Here is my code:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
 
const useDailyNotification = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const setupNotifications = async () => {
            try {
                // 1. Request permissions
                const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync({
                    ios: {
                        allowAlert: true,
                        allowBadge: true,
                        allowSound: true,
                    },
                });
 
                if (status !== 'granted') {
                    console.warn('Notification permissions not granted');
                    return;
                }
 
                // 2. Cancel any existing notifications to avoid duplicates
                await Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync();
 
                // 3. Set up the notification category (with the Snooze action)
                await Notifications.setNotificationCategoryAsync('DAILY_REMINDER', [
                    {
                        identifier: 'SNOOZE_ACTION',
                        buttonTitle: 'Snooze 2 hours',
                        options: {
                            isDestructive: false,
                            isAuthenticationRequired: false,
                        },
                    },
                ]);
 
                // 4. Schedule the new daily notification
                await scheduleNotification();
                console.log('Daily notification scheduled successfully for 18:00');
 
                // 5. Set up notification response listener
                const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
                    handleNotificationResponse
                );
 
                // Cleanup the listener when unmounting
                return () => {
                    subscription.remove();
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error setting up notifications:', error);
            }
        };
 
        setupNotifications();
    }, []);
 
    const handleNotificationResponse = async (response) => {
        const { actionIdentifier } = response;
 
        if (actionIdentifier === 'SNOOZE_ACTION') {
            await scheduleSnoozeNotification();
        }
    };
 
    const scheduleNotification = async () => {
        try {
            await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
                content: {
                    title: 'Title',
                    body: 'Body.',
                    sound: true,
                    categoryIdentifier: 'DAILY_REMINDER',
                },
                trigger: {
                    hour: 18,
                    minute: 0,
                    repeats: true,
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error scheduling notification:', error);
            throw error;
        }
    };
 
    const scheduleSnoozeNotification = async () => {
        try {
            // Schedule a one-time notification for 2 hours from now
            const snoozeTime = new Date();
            snoozeTime.setHours(snoozeTime.getHours() + 2);
 
            await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
                content: {
                    title: 'Title (Snoozed)',
                    body: 'Body.',
                    sound: true,
                    categoryIdentifier: 'DAILY_REMINDER',
                },
                trigger: {
                    date: snoozeTime,
                },
            });
 
            console.log('Snooze notification scheduled for 2 hours from now');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error scheduling snooze notification:', error);
        }
    };
};
 
export default useDailyNotification;


Try trigger notifications with notifee. That can take care of snoozing, too, if you pass an action to the trigger.

Ive decided to keep trying with expo-notifications, as ive read online you cant test Notifee on Expo Go. And its my only way of testing the app as i don't have a Mac. I managed to fix my notification by adding type: "daily" in the trigger."trigger: {
type: "daily", hour: 18,
minute: 0,
repeats: true,
}," But i have put snooze to rest for now.
